Do diakrino and diakrisis mean the same thing?
Why are is one used in Romans 14:1, and the other used in Romans 14:23? Any reason of meaning, or are they forms of the same word?

διακρίνω is a verb while διάκρισις is a noun derived from it.

This should expose the popular level superficial learning among christians which seeks to analyse Greek by interlinear, and then also fall into the trap of shallow superficial translations like YTL for their study. I recommend buying John Dobson Learn NT Greek, and use duolingo, and theword.net and MyBible phone app for free and detailed lexicons for tools for learning.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

@Michael16. Am not a big fan of Dobson's Greek. The first half of the book is OK, for someone who is just sampling the language, but the second half is just weak. I'd rather suggest Mounce.

The Greek words “diakrisis” and “diakrino” are related but they can have different meanings in these contexts.
“diakrisis” is a noun and it refers to the act of judgment or discernment. It’s used in the context of distinguishing, deciding, or passing sentence on something.

Definition: the act of judgment
Usage: distinguishing; hence: deciding, passing sentence on; the act
of judgment, discernment.

On the other hand, “Diakrino” is a verb and it means to distinguish, to judge, or to discern one thing from another. It can also imply doubt, hesitation, or wavering. This word is used, often referring to making judgments or discernments.

Definition: to distinguish, to judge
Usage: I separate, distinguish, discern one thing from another; I
doubt, hesitate, waver.



“diakriseis” is used in the phrase "not for the purpose of passing judgment on his reasonings/opinions". It's advising believers to accept those who are weak in faith without engaging in disputes over differing opinions.

“diakrinomenos” is used in the phrase “But whoever has doubts is condemned if he eats, because the eating is not from faith”. This verse is says that if a person has doubts about what they are doing, particularly in the context of eating certain foods, and they go against their conscience, it is considered sinful.
Conclusion/Summary:
Diakrisis (noun): Refers to the act of judgment or discernment. It’s used in the context of distinguishing, deciding, or passing sentence on something. It’s used to advise believers to accept those who are weak in faith without engaging in disputes over differing opinions. So, in this context, “diakrisis” is about discerning differences in opinions or beliefs, but not allowing these differences to become a source of dispute or division among believers.
Diakrino (verb): Means to distinguish, judge, or discern one thing from another. It can also imply doubt, hesitation, or wavering. In Romans 14:23, it’s used in the context of having doubts about eating certain foods against one’s conscience, which is considered sinful.
So, while “diakrisis” and “diakrino” are forms of the same root word and have related meanings, they are used differently in the context of both verses.

Thanks for answering. Is the kind of doubt in Romans 14:23 a feeling of anxiety / uncertainty about an act or a genuine conviction that is being violated? For example 1) someone can have a genuine but misplaced conviction that eating something is wrong and for them to eat would be a sin as they violate their conviction. But what about 2) someone who doesnt believe it is wrong but has anxiety about it or someone who isn't sure but believes it probably isnt? I struggle with worrying about whether many things are sins and ask if the "doubts" is 1 2 or both? Could the diakrino mean judge as wrong?

Both words refer to discernment and/or making judgement. διακρίνω is a verb, meaning to discern. διάκρισις is a noun, meaning the act of discerning. So, the two words are synonymous by definition. However, they are two distinct words. One is a derivative of the other, not an alternate form of the same word. They can be used interchangeably by definition, but they are different parts of speech altogether. One is a verb, the other a noun.
